# Easier way to synchronize 2 threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I wan't to be sure that some piece of my code within the main thread will be executed after some piece of code executed withing the secondary thread. Here's what I got:

```
    final Object lock = new Object();
    final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            synchronized(lock) {
                System.out.println("qwerty");
                lock.notify();
            }
        }
    });

    synchronized(lock) {
        t.start();
        lock.wait();
    }

    System.out.println("absolutely sure, qwerty is above");
```

1. Is it correct solution?
2. Any shorter ways to do the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your main thread needs to initiate the secondary thread's processing, an [Exchanger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html) would be the simplest solution.

If the secondary thread is independent, then some form of [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) would be appropriate.

---

An example using Exchanger (with proper exception handling). The one Exchanger could be substituted with two queues.

```
public static void main(String[] argv)
throws Exception
{
    final Exchanger<String> exchanger = new Exchanger<String>();
    new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            try
            {
                String s = exchanger.exchange("");
                System.out.println(s);
                exchanger.exchange("this came from subthread");
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                System.out.println("interrupted while waiting for message");
            }
        }
    }).start();

    exchanger.exchange("this came from main thread");
    String s = exchanger.exchange("");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: @Jeffrey - thanks. I took the links that Google gave me, without checking the JDK version.

Comment: @John - there are reasons that there's a lot of broken multi-threaded code out there. IMO the biggest is that people don't think about how to communicate between threads.

Comment: @parisfal someone probably saw Exchanger and had no idea what it meant so a -1?

Comment: @parsifal: Thanks for `Exchanger`, that solves the next problem I wanted to post.

Answer (score 13):

Things like *notify()* and *wait()* are really low-level synchronization primitives.

You should use higher-level abstractions whenever possible, like in this case, say, a *CountDownLatch*.

The following is just an example that should get you started (for example the timeout issues aren't taken into account here):

```
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("qwerty");
            latch.countDown();
        }
    });

    t.start();
    latch.await();

    System.out.println("absolutely sure, qwerty as been printed");
```

Low-level things like *wait* and *notify* are really just low-level Java idiosynchrasies that you shouldn't be concerned with (unless you're writing concurrency APIs).

Additionally, I'd suggest reading the amazing book: *Java Concurrency In Practice*.

Answer (score -1):

```
final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("qwerty");
    }
});

t.start();
t.join();

System.out.println("absolutely sure, qwerty is above");
```

Comment: Just saw that while it solves the primitive example above, it doesn't do what the question specified if the subthread should do something else ...

Answer (score -4):

The best solution for the code you have given is:

```
System.out.println("qwerty");
System.out.println("absolutely sure, qwerty is above");
```

Don't use threading when you don't need it.

But if you know what you're doing with the thread, then @DoubleMalt's solution is the way to go (`t.join()`).

You'd also probably find it worth reading http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/